# Should I explicitly implement an interface when I already extend a class that implements it?

Tags: java, oop

If I have an interface and an abstract class like `AbstractMojo` and `Mojo` from the Maven Plugin API, should I explicitly implement `Mojo`, when `AbstractMojo` already implements that interface?

```
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo implements Mojo {
    // like this?
    // ...
}

public class OtherMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    // or like this?
    // ...
}
```

Does either of these class declarations have any benefits over the other?

Comment: One is explicit. One is implicit. If you want to bring the reader's attention to the fact that you are implementing the interface, you might prefer to be explicit. If you think it just adds confusion, you might prefer to leave it implicit.

Comment: Similar question : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271364/implementing-an-interface-already-implemented-by-a-parent-class

Answer (score 3):

The question you should ask yourself is, "why would I implement something that has already been implemented in an upper hierarchical level?"

You don't need to because any abstract methods that you didn't implement in the abstract class (belonging originally in the interface), will have to implemented in your concrete class which extends the abstract class. So no point in implementing in the concrete class and the abstract class as well

Answer (score 2):

A third reason to not use an extraneous `implements`: the reader expects all interface methods to have its first implementation here.

So a call to the super-method might be forgotten (by an inattentive developer).

It is misleading.

The generated javadoc will list all implemented interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not. You can implement AbstractMojo, but it is redundant if you have already extend class that implements it.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone who uses an IDE can easily see which interfaces your class extends, even displayed in the hierarchy (e.g. ctrl + T, ctrl + T in Eclipse) or look in the javadoc.

Therefore, making this explicit should not be necessary and can clutter up your code if you extend many interfaces. The code is functionally identical.